# does wireless access point support internet from ISP

Tags: router, wifi, access-point

As I know a **wifi router** can be used establish a local wireless network by connecting ethernet cable to it from ISP, Is it possible to do same thing with **wireless access point**?

Answer (score 0):

No.  A wireless access point is equivalent to a layer 2 switch.  It has no routing capability.